# Return true from newly requested record created successfully by entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am working on ASP.NET MVC app and using jquery ajax function on client side. I am wondering is there any default way that entity framework tells that record has created successfully. I know on single record entry, entity framework response back newly created record {PK} ID but what about with multiple entries in single linq?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can return a true if your request was created successfully.

```
context.SaveChanges()
```

The above code is used to save an entity in EF, it returns the number of rows affected. (so you could look for anything greater than 0)

Answer (score 0):

I think that if there is no exception thrown, then the records are inserted and you can return true.